# Cannot bottom align image in jumbotron

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to bottom align an img in a jumbotron, but cannot figure it out.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more »</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding the following to the CSS

```
.vertical-bottom {
  display: flex;
  align-items: bottom;
}
```

And then added the additional class to the DIV containing the img

```
<div class="col-lg-4 text-center vertical-bottom">
```

This didn't work, why is it so hard to vertically align things in bootstrap?

Comment: The issue doesn't lie with bootstrap. Vertically centering things has been semi-difficult till flex-box was supported. Bootstrap 4 however allows you to use flex-box classes that work with their column/grid system. Back to the question, what result are you trying to achieve? The image will be horizontally centered but below the title, text, and button?

Comment: @hunter-mitchell I'd like the image to be horizontally centered and bottom aligned to the side of the div containing the title, text, and button.  So 1 row with 2 columns both bottom aligned.  I thought about trying to figure out the height of the div with title, text, and button and then setting the top margin for the image to get bottom alignment.  However, I'm not sure how to get the height of that div?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 has a really good grid system with flexbox support. I'd recommend you use it (without you need to remove the float on both the columns and manually position each column so you can set the children height to 100%). When i get a change ill throw an example up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a kind of code:

**[Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/jKAA6L9F2a)**

**Css**:
*The media query is set to 1200 because I see you're using col-lg-xx*

```
@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  .flex_container img{
      object-fit: contain;
      object-position: 100% 100%;
  }
  .flex_container {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

**Html**:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row flex_container">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more »</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 text-center flex_container">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" style="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  But I might start to migrate to Bootstrap 4, seems to offer some better flexbox support as suggested by @hunter-mitchell.

Comment: Although, I seem to lose control over horizontal placement.  The text_center does nothing...

Comment: @user13317 use justify-content: center; instead of text-align:center;